# Mongodb ConnectionPoolExpired between it’s replica members

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, percona

I have cross site replication enabled using percona mongodb operator, mongo version 6.0.4-3
we are using oracle load balancer to expose the pods and we noticed a drop happens suddenly in the connection and when we check the logs we found the below:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-12T19:15:01.043+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONNPOOL", "id":22572,   "ctx":"ShardRegistry","msg":"Dropping all pooled connections","attr":{"hostAndPort":"10.11.10.18:27017","error":"ConnectionPoolExpired: Pool for 10.11.10.18:27017 has expired."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-12T19:19:31.387+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONNPOOL", "id":22572,   "ctx":"ShardRegistry","msg":"Dropping all pooled connections","attr":{"hostAndPort":"10.11.10.1:27017","error":"ConnectionPoolExpired: Pool for 10.11.10.1:27017 has expired."}}
```

please note the IPs mentioned in the logs is for the DR site.

here the graph from the LB:
[LB graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKcXe.png)

I noticed the drop happened every 2 hours also number of connections varies from 3K to 5K

any ideas?

I tried to find and understand why mongo drops all the connections but still no luck